# Derive an explicit expression for $P_e=P(\psi_1|\psi_2)P(\psi_1)+P(\psi_2|\psi_1)P(\psi_2)$

Tags: vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, cryptography, quantum-mechanics

I am currently working with an exercise set about discriminating between two different quantum states. We consider a 2-dimensional Hilbert space expanded by $|\phi_1\rangle$, $|\phi_2\rangle$. The system is secretly prepared into one of the following states at random:

$|\psi_1\rangle=|{\phi_1}\rangle \tag{1}\\$
$|\psi_2\rangle=\text{cos}\theta|\phi_1\rangle+\text{sin}\theta |\phi_2\rangle \tag{2}$

Where angle $\theta$ is a real number between 0 and $\frac{\pi}{2}$

We are handed one of these states and want to indentify if we receive $|\psi_1\rangle$ or $|\psi_2\rangle$.

To start with we consider another basis $|e_1\rangle$, $|e_2\rangle$ which is rotated with respect to $|\phi_1\rangle$ and $|\phi_2\rangle$:

$|e_1\rangle=\text{cos}\alpha|\phi_1\rangle+\text{sin}\alpha|\phi_2\rangle\\$

$|e_2\rangle=-\text{sin}\alpha|\phi_1\rangle+\text{cos}\alpha|\phi_2\rangle$

Where angle $\alpha$ originates from the fact that basis $|e_1\rangle$, $|e_2\rangle$ is rotated relative to $|\phi_1\rangle$, $|\phi_2\rangle$.

I have derived the following expressions using $|\phi_1\rangle$, $|\phi_2\rangle$ for the projectors corresponding to a measurement in basis $|e_1\rangle$, $|e_2\rangle$:

$|\phi_1\rangle=-\text{sin}\alpha |e_2\rangle \tag{3}$

$|\phi_2\rangle=\text{sin}\alpha |e_1\rangle+\text{cos} \alpha |e_2\rangle \tag{4}$

Now; We want to use basis $|e_1\rangle$, $|e_2\rangle$ to discriminate between the states $|\psi_1\rangle$, $|\psi_2\rangle$. The average probability of picking the wrong state is:

$P_e=P(\psi_1|\psi_2)P(\psi_1)+P(\psi_2|\psi_1)P(\psi_2)$

We want to derive an explicit expression for $P_e$ using (1), (2), (3) and (4).

Contemporary solution:

I insert (3) and (4) into (1) and (2) to get:

$|\psi_1\rangle=-\text{sin}\alpha|e_2\rangle\\$

$|\psi_2\rangle=\text{sin}\theta\text{sin}\alpha |e_1\rangle+\text{sin}(\theta-\alpha)|e_2\rangle$

I remember that the probability of a quantum state is given as $\text{P}(a,b)= \langle a|b \rangle ^2$. Using this approach, I get:

$P(\psi_1)=\langle\psi_1|\psi_1\rangle^2=\text{sin}^2\alpha$

$P(\psi_2)=\langle\psi_2|\psi_2\rangle^2=\text{sin}^2\theta\text{sin}^2\alpha + \text{sin}^2(\theta-\alpha)$

$P(\psi_1,\psi_2)=\langle\psi_1|\psi_2\rangle^2=-\text{sin}\alpha\text{sin}(\theta-\alpha)$

$P(\psi_2,\psi_1)=\langle\psi_2|\psi_1\rangle^2=-\text{sin}\alpha\text{sin}(\theta-\alpha)$

$P_e=-\text{sin}\alpha\text{sin}(\theta-\alpha)[\text{sin}^2\theta\text{sin}^2\alpha + \text{sin}^2(\theta-\alpha)]-\text{sin}^3\alpha\text{sin}(\theta-\alpha)$

I do not have the solutions to the exercise available, so I have cannot determine whether this approach is correct. I would greatly appreciate any help to explain if this approach is correct or if another approach is better.

Comment: Mathjax doesn't know about bras and kets. I've usually typset them as | \langle and |\rangle respectively, with a braket as \langle \mid \rangle. I'm sure there's a better way, but that's the best I've found.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I have manually updated them now, I hope it is readable.

Comment: To the math, I think you might be misremembering some of the fundamentals of quantum mechanics. It doesn't make sense to talk about the probability of a state. We always talk about the probability of observing some eigenvalue of a hermitian operator *given* a state. This probability is the squared magnitude of the projection onto the eigenspace of our chosen eigenvalue. Does that help?

Comment: To maybe be more precise: $\langle \psi_1 \mid \psi_1 \rangle$ is always just $1$. The probability of observing $\psi_1$ given you are in the state $\psi_1$ is, of course, $1$. You need some prior distribution for the probability of being in $\psi_1$ or $\psi_2$ to do this problem. If one isn't given, a safe bet is usually that each is equally likely.

Comment: I think it makes sence physically, but I struggle to transfer this knowledge into a mathematical description of the probability of observing eigenvalues given the states above. I will research 'Introduction to QM' by David Griffiths to find and answer, but your comment definitely helps guiding me in the right direction.

Comment: I should add that the "correct" way to approach a problem like this is through the density matrix formalism, which is designed specifically for talking about initial "states" where you only know the distribution of initial kets and not which particular ket state your system is in.